# Using Airbrake in Rails projekt got error while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, airbrake

I try to use Airbrake in my Rails 4.2 project, but when I run

```
sudo rake airbrake:test
```

I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
Airbrake::Error: the 'default' notifier isn't configured
```

can anyone tell me whats the problem?

thanks!

Comment: Not enough info. Did you configure airbrake at all? Did you follow the setup instructions on https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have inadvertently upgraded to the [new Airbrake v5 gem](https://airbrake.io/blog/notifier/our-new-ruby-notifier).

You can:

1. Follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/docs/Migration_guide_from_v4_to_v5.md) to migrate from airbrake v4 to v5
2. Lock airbrake to v4, in the gemfile, e.g. something like `gem 'airbrake', '~> 4.3'`