# How can I get airbrake out of my development and test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, airbrake

I've been having major problems with the `airbrake` gem that is seriously impeding my work flow lately. As an example, I am working on some front end stuff with coffeescript. When I make an error like a typo or anything, I get this error message:[image]

As you can see from the image, this does not help me at all whatsoever and it takes me absolutely forever to figure out what's wrong. A second example is running a rake test.

When I have airbrake and run `rake test`, if I were to say have something wrong with mhy configuration, I get this horrible long string of text that looks like this:

[image]

Basically what the picture is saying is that I didn't specify the name of my localhost test database but you wouldn't necessarily know that based on the errors that airbrake yields.

In my `airbrake.rbg` I have the following configuration settings:

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.project_key = ENV['AIRBRAKE_API_KEY']
  config.host = "#{ENV['AIRBRAKE_HOST']}:#{ENV['AIRBRAKE_PORT'].to_i}"
  config.project_id = ENV['AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID']
  config.ignore_environments = %w(development test)
end

class Airbrake::Sender
  def json_api_enabled?
    true
  end
end
```

As you can see, I should have airbrake configured correctly to ignore both my test and development database but this is not working. Has anyone had this problem before. I would really love to fix this once and for all so its not a huge problem anymore. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just remove that file and put that code in `environments/production.rb`?

Comment: I've tried this but I then recieve 'Airbrake::Error: the 'default' notifier isn't configured"

Comment: What version of Airbrake are you running?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475197/using-airbrake-in-rails-projekt-got-error-while-testing

Comment: Can you try to upgrade to the latest version of Airbrake. This error has been fixed ages ago.

Comment: No, that version was released about 9 months ago, which is super out-of-date now :) Make sure to have airbrake-5.5.0 & airbrake-ruby-1.5.0 installed

Comment: Got it, yup that's right. I was looking at the wrong ruby gems page. This resolved it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug in an older version of Airbrake that has been resolved in newer versions.

Try updating Airbrake in your Gemfile to the [latest version](https://rubygems.org/gems/airbrake).

```
gem 'airbrake', '~> 5.5'
```